# How to create YTD column in matrix reports

Tags: reporting, administration

I have a requirement to create a YTD column based on the login history of the year (i.e) the login history for the current physical year of the user .I need this to be done in matrix report.

[image]

when you look at the screen shot the YTD calculates the logins only on the current physical year(jan14-mar14).Grand total should display the asusal the entire total. Does this can be achieved in matrix report? or by anyother reports.